# How to Dispatch catalog_product_collection_load_after zero products in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, event-observer, collection, product-collection

I noticed that in Magento 2.1 the event `catalog_product_collection_load_after` is dispatched only when the collection has at least one product. **How can I make Magento dispatch it also when the collection is empty?**

**UPDATE**

I thought to dispatch `catalog_product_collection_load_after` event also when the collection is empty to make some changes to the layout only when the products count is zero, but I noticed that once the collection is loaded the layout has been already rendered, so it is not possible to make any further changes to the layout. This can be done in some other ways?

Thanks.!

Comment: why you required this? what you try to do this.

Comment: In the beginning I thought to dispatch the event also when the collection was empty to do some layout changing in the observer. Then I discovered that, once the collection is loaded the layout has already been "rendered" and I am not able to modify it.

Comment: That means the question does not make sense anymore, right? The event exists to modify the loaded products, so it's only needed if the collection is not empty. Can you update the question with your real problem?